# Tricky CSS Tangle: Link styles from separate divs all seeming to pull style from elsewhere

Tags: css, hyperlink

Problem: My page header is laid out like this(Sorry, I don't have enough rep just yet to post images directly, or post more than two links. Which is why I have []ed the http:// in the second two links to get past it in case some of you would like to see the problem through Imgur without actually visiting the web page in question):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn0fj.png

But when any link in the header area (and these links are separated in completely different classes and divs) is being clicked on, (I believe it's called "active"), the whole section of links goes cray. The Login/Register links fly off of the page, and the nav links lose their float:right attribute. I've looked through all of my ".class a:link, a:visited a:hover, a:active"'s and can't find any style that should be affecting them! I'll try to describe my method in a way that someone may be able to flag an error in my CSS syntax, although I think the issue may not be so simple.

The effects of clicking a link anywhere in the header (Notice I say "header, but this header isn't styled as a single header div, it's a series of stacked, separate divs floating left or right):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oYtG.png

Or:

[http://]i.stack.imgur.com/W87fC.png

Or even flying off of the page:

[http://]i.stack.imgur.com/mB0Zh.png

See www.gamemode.org for the live example of this.

My style sheet is huge, but I think I can describe this in a way that I can achieve an answer from simple CSS fundamental tips rather than a "paste this in" fix.

I have been styling my links in the header of GameMode.org so that I have a top bar who's login/ register links float to the left, and a lower nav section where the navigation links float to the right. The way that I've been styling is as follows:

HTML:

```
 <div class="class_name"><a>Link</a></div>
 <div class="another_class_name"><a>Link</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .class_name a:link, a:visited, a:active
 {
 margin:0em 0em 0em 0em;
 float:left;
 color:somecolor;
 (etc)
 }

 .class_name a:hover
 {
 (simple hover effect)
 }

 .another_class_name a:link, a:visited, a:active
 {
 margin:0em 0em 0em 0em;
 float:right;
 color:somecolor;
 (etc)
 }     

 .another_class_name a:hover
 {
 (simple hover effect)
 }
```

Is there something wrong with these styles?
Is there anyone here generous enough to look into my webpage and styles at www.gamemode.org and try and find my problem? I've looked for many hours using google chrome web tools and cannot seem to find the source of the links going crazy when active (while being clicked), although I have noticed that they do not act this way when local styling is removed.

[Edit: I would add in some of the CSS, but as I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue, I can't do so- Anyone who want's to look into it can easily view and tamper with the CSS as I normally do, with Google Chrome's Inspect Element]

**[Edit II: does the above code not style only links within that div? Example: | .this_class a:link, a:active { color:red; } | would be the same as "Style inactive links and active links in class="this_class" with red color." Is this incorrect?**

Comment: Note: I'm still tampering with the elements without success. However, I'll mention that it appears as if links that are in the active state seem to be floating left instead of right in the nav area. I still haven't figured out what is occurring with the top, left floating links that seem to disappear off screen when in the active state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have tons of a:active styles overwriting and contradicting your default ones. 
For instance, the ones bothering you are width and margin set at 671 and 223 lines of your styles.css 
Get rid of those and everything will work fine.

Here's a screenshot, with the problematic items:

http://prntscr.com/14ttsx

change this:

```
.top a:link, a:visited, a:active
{
float:left;
margin:0% 1% 0% 2%;
font-size:19pt;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

to this:

```
.top a:link, a:visited, a:active
{
float:left;
margin:0;
width: auto;
font-size:19pt;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

This way you won't wreck the other styled links.

The problem with other styles affecting the ones at the top is the following:

```
.server_slot a:link, a:active, a:visited {
...
}
```

That part of code is targeting active link in the server_slot class but also ALL active and ALL visited links. You should change it to:

```
.server_slot a:link, .server_slot a:active, .server_slot a:visited {
...
}
```

Additional random advice:

- Don't mix units, in one rule you are using font-size in em and in another in pt. Use one and stick with it
- But don't use pt, unless it's for print, here's why: http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Comment: I'm not arguing with you, as you doubtlessly have many years of experience more than I with .CSS- However, I'd appreciate it if you'd explain the issue of the overwriting styles. With the code - .class a:link a:visited, a:hover, a:active - I'm meaning to style only the a:vis a:act etc of the .class that I list before it. Am I doing this incorrectly? If so, how do I style only the links of the class in question? A link to a page on the topic would suffice. Removing the styles as you mentioned completely de-formats all links on the page.

Comment: About the units, thank you, I have been going through and re-unit(ing)  after noticing my deviation. Once I get these links fixed, that will be my next change. I'm trying to follow your advice, but am destroying the style of the page in doing so. If you've tried actually removing those styles, you'll see that I either need those styles, or need to learn to style each separate div with its own link style set without affecting outside elements not included in the div. See Edit II

Comment: No problem at all, you see the problem is that both of those styles are affecting the same items which isn't really desirable. For instance, your links in the headers get margin: -7% 0% 128% 0%; and then again margin:0% 1% 0% 2%; this makes it difficult to inspect and debug so you should maybe reorganize those styles.

Comment: I edited my answer to not wreck the other styled links on the page.

Comment: EDIT: just saw your reply. reading now. For example, to remove the margin from the top might be necessary if the style is applying to other divs, but removing it obviously removes the style from the element that needs it also. How can I style links of a single div without affect the styles of links in any other div? .this_class a:link { margin:1em; } seems to be applying margins to more than just .this_class according to what you're suggesting.

Comment: I added an explanation to why this is happening in my original reply

Comment: Ok, you're a life-saver. Or a CSS fixer. Same difference. Your final statement about why the styles where affecting everything completely made sense. Now if 50% of society could be %50 as helpful as this, we might be in business.

Comment: using inspect element/firebug in browser really helps - a lot of times we try to logic through the linear progress of our sheet to try and figure out why something is as it is. Cut to the chase. Ask the browser what it's seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The one of problems  is on line 222 of style.css

```
.server_slot a:link, a:active, a:visited {
    color: white;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Geo',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin: -7% 0 128%;
    max-height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5% 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
```

remove `widht:100%;`

but I think it is not the all,

Comment: Thank you. I just went in and fixed that. No further luck. I'm chomping off large chunks of the CSS, one at a time, trying to pinpoint the issue. Also working on dividing the main CSS up into separate stylesheets. This is what I get for tangling 900+ lines of CSS into a single style sheet.

Comment: That did do a great deal! The nav links are now much less trippy.

Comment: Still a ways to go though. *continues chomping through CSS